# Parse filename string and extract parent at specific level using shell

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a filename as a string, say `filname="a/b/c/d.png"`.

Is there a general method to extract the parent directory at a given level using ONLY [shell parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion)?

I.e. I would like to extract "level 1" and return `c` or "level 2" and return `b`.

Explicitly, I DO NOT want to get the entire parent path (i.e. `a/b/c/`, which is the result of `${filename%/*}`).

Comment: Which are you using, `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this with just parameter expansion. Why are you limited like that?

Comment: At this point I have 3+ ways to do this using unix commands, I'm just being stubborn ;)

Comment: @Barmar prefer `zsh`

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no parameter expansion operator for this in either bash or zsh. You want something that treats `x/y/z/...` as an array with `/` as the delimiters, and then indexes it, but there's no such operator.

Comment: @Barmar Saying 'no such operator' when it comes to `zsh` is usually a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using just shell parameter expansion, assuming bash, you can first transform the path into an array (splitting on `/`) and then ask for specific array indexes:

```
filename=a/b/c/d.png
IFS=/
filename_array=( $filename )
unset IFS

echo "0 = ${filename_array[0]}"
echo "1 = ${filename_array[1]}"
echo "2 = ${filename_array[2]}"
echo "3 = ${filename_array[3]}"
```

Running the above produces:

```
0 = a
1 = b
2 = c
3 = d.png
```

These indexes are the reverse of what you want, but a little
arithmetic should fix that.

Comment: That's not a shell parameter expansion operator.

Comment: ...and now it is.

Comment: I don't think this is what he's looking for, either. Array indexing isn't an expansion operator. See https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion

Comment: I think we'll let the OP decide whether or not this is what they're asking about.

Comment: `IFS=/ read -ra filename_array <<<"$filename"` instead of setting IFS and using word splitting and then unsetting IFS.

Comment: In a function `local IFS` protects the global value.

Comment: This solution is subject to glob expansion

Answer (score 1):

Using `zsh`, the `:h` [modifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) trims the final component off a path in variable expansion.

The `(s:...:)` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) can be used to split the contents of a variable. Combine those with normal array indexing where a negative index goes from the end of the array, and...

```sh
$ filename=a/b/c/d.png
$ print $filename:h
a/b/c
$ level=1
$ print ${${(s:/:)filename:h}[-level]}
c
$ level=2
$ print ${${(s:/:)filename:h}[-level]}
b
```

You could also use [array subscript flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Subscript-Flags) instead to avoid the nested expansion:

```sh
$ level=1
$ print ${filename[(ws:/:)-level-1]}
c
$ level=2
$ print ${filename[(ws:/:)-level-1]}
b
```

`w` makes the index of a scalar split on words instead of by character, and `s:...:` has the same meaning, to say what to split on. Have to subtract one from the level to skip over the trailing `d.png`, since it's not stripped off already like the first way.

Answer (score 1):

The `:h` (head) and `:t` (tail) expansion modifiers in `zsh` accept digits to specify a level; they can be combined to get a subset of the path:

```
> filname="a/b/c/d.png"
> print ${filname:t2}
c/d.png
> print ${filname:t2:h1}
c
> print ${filname:t3:h1}
b
```

If the level is in a variable, then the `F` modifier can be used to repeat the `h` modifier a specific number of times:

```
> for i in 1 2 3; printf '%s: %s\n' $i ${filname:F(i)h:t}
1: c
2: b
3: a
```

Comment: `:h` and `:t` taking a count was added in zsh 5.8; won't work in older versions btw.

Answer (score 0):

If using `printf` (a shell builtin) is allowed then this will do the trick in `bash`:

```
filename='a/b/c/d.png'
level=2

printf -v spaces '%*s' $level
pattern=${spaces//?/'/*'}
component=${filename%$pattern}
component=${component##*/}
echo $component
```

prints out

```
b
```

You can assign different values to the variable `level`.